# Using excel and modifying string based on search function

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to get a value or all values similar to below in excel:

```
#123 maybe some text and date 12/17/209
#048309 maybe some text and date 12/17/209
#9385 maybe some text and date 12/17/209
```

I want to get the value proceeding the # however, I am not sure if there is an easier function? I want it to find the # then get however many numbers proceeds it. I am familiar with regex not with excel functions unfortunately.

Sorry for vagueness:

I was trying to use an IF() supplying a # as the find operation for the character I just couldnt manage to get the number as I was trying to use RIGHT() to filter after the #. What I found with the RIGHT() function is that it expects a parameter for count and so would have to be dynamic so I dropped that idea.

Comment: The question is still vague, please post what code you have come up with.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I have but also found the solution thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will get the numbers directly after `#`:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND("#",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#",A1))-FIND("#",A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow Scott thanks I was trying to use the RIGHT and left, I do not understand the statement but I will work through it and get my understanding more up to scratch with excel formulas. Thank you :)